# Why the code doesn't recognize the assigned variable?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program in Python 3 that takes an int year larger than 1970 as an input and returns the increase in temperature from 1970 until that year. The formulas and constants are given. Python throws me an error:

```
File "4.5.py", line 28, in <module>
    int_years = int_year - 1970
NameError: name 'int_year' is not defined
```

I am a beginner in Python so I have browsed possible solutions, but could not find any working ones.

```
def user_input():
    while True:
        int_year = int(input("Please enter a year greater than 1970 " ))
        try:
            if int_year > 1970:
                break
            else:
                print("Please enter a year greater than 1970")
        except ValueError:
            print ("It is not a valid year. Try again. ")
    return int_year

"""CO2 level of January 1970"""
c0 = 325.03

"""Current levels of CO2"""
c1 = 411.97

"""Difference in CO2 levels between 1970 and now"""
differenceCO = c1-c0

"""The average CO2 increase per year since 1970"""
per_year_changedCO = ((differenceCO)/(2019-1970))

"""Diffrence in years between 1970 and user input year"""
int_years = int_year - 1970

"""A projected CO2 level in user input year"""
int_year_changedCO = c0+((int_years)*(per_year_changedCO))

"""A projected RF in any year"""
RF = 5.35*(math.log((int_year_changedCO)/(c0)))

"""Increase in temperature from 1970 to user input year"""
def predict_increase():
  temp_int_year = 0.5 * RF
  return temp_int_year

print(temp_int_year)
```

I expect the program to recognize the variables I use in functions. Overall, I will appreciate any comments on the code.

Comment: Well, it's just the opposite: by default, variables used in functions are supposed to stay local to these functions and not to leak into the global scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the time you execute the line `int_years = int_year - 1970`, you haven't defined `int_year` in scope. The only place you've used it up to that point is within the `user_input()` function - but variables defined within functions are *only* defined *within* the functions - not outside of them. To get the value of `int_year` outside of the function, you need to call the function:

```
int_year = user_input()
int_years = int_year - 1970
```

or simply do them both at once:

```
int_years = user_input() - 1970
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. You made it very clear. I obvioulsly didnt know that i have a variable outside the function as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

`return int_year`

By inserting this instruction, you tell the interpreter to return the value `int_year` has **at that moment**. Any further usage of this variable leads to an error, because the variable is no longer defined

Answer (score 0):

You define int_year within the scope of the user_input, but that is not accessible outwith that function [(more info about that here)](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html)

Rather than reference the variable directly you want to get the return value of the function (which is the value of int_year because of the line 'return int_year'):

```
int_years = user_input() - 1970
```

**Edit for comment above**

```
def user_input():
    try:
        int_year = int(input("Please enter a year greater than 1970"))
        if int_year < 1970:
            print("Invalid year, please enter a value greater than 1970")
            int_year = user_input()
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a number")
        int_year = user_input()
    return int_year
```

Comment: Thak you for answer and the link which was very helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

you dont call your functions anywhere, variables temp_int_year and int_year are `Local variables of functions` and they can't be accessed from outside, when the function call has finished

you need to call function and save return value into  temp_int_year and int_year:

```
int_year = user_input()

temp_int_year = predict_increase()
print(temp_int_year)
```

> NOTE: you have the same mistake with temp_int_year

full code:

```
import math
def user_input():
    while True:
        int_year = int(input("Please enter a year greater than 1970 " ))
        try:
            if int_year > 1970:
                break
            else:
                print("Please enter a year greater than 1970")
        except ValueError:
            print ("It is not a valid year. Try again. ")
    return int_year

int_year = user_input()


"""CO2 level of January 1970"""
c0 = 325.03

"""Current levels of CO2"""
c1 = 411.97

"""Difference in CO2 levels between 1970 and now"""
differenceCO = c1-c0

"""The average CO2 increase per year since 1970"""
per_year_changedCO = ((differenceCO)/(2019-1970))

"""Diffrence in years between 1970 and user input year"""
int_years = int_year - 1970

"""A projected CO2 level in user input year"""
int_year_changedCO = c0+((int_years)*(per_year_changedCO))

"""A projected RF in any year"""
RF = 5.35*(math.log((int_year_changedCO)/(c0)))

"""Increase in temperature from 1970 to user input year"""
def predict_increase():
  temp_int_year = 0.5 * RF
  return temp_int_year

temp_int_year = predict_increase()
print(temp_int_year)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have edited the code according to your suggestion. The problem now is that the interpreter asks me twice, not once, to enter a year if i put the year bigger than 1970. How could i fix it and have the interpreter to ask only once? P.S. I thought "break" inside the function would solve it but i did not. What is the usage of "break" than? Thank you in advance

Comment: I have edited the function like this: def user_input():
    while True:
        int_year = int(input("Please enter a year greater than 1970 " ))
        try:
            if int_year > 1970:
                break
            else:
                print("The year you have entered is smaller than 1970")
        except ValueError:
            print ("It is not a valid year. Try again. ")
    return int_year

Comment: i have realised i didn't mention you in my answer before. Would you please answer my question above?

Comment: @MargaritaShablya 'break' is a keyword to break out of a loop. In your function, it will end the 'while True' infinite loop. If you don't want to end it but actually try again, then 'continue' is what you're looking for - instead of ending the loop execution it skips this iteration and moves to the next.
Also re. the try/except code - the line of code which triggers the error needs to be contained within the try block, not before it (i.e. the int_year = int() line). This will still throw an error if the input is not a number.

Comment: @MargaritaShablya I've added a code snippet to my answer below since it's easier to do formatting there than in comments, hopefully it might be useful. Would be my way of approaching that function

Comment: (Also, just noticed that the reason you would have been getting it asking twice is that I think you have the year check the wrong way round in your snippets - shouldn't it be 'if int_year < 1970', not '>'?)